# Memory Error while using Keras in Text Generation with LSTM Model

Tags: python, text, keras, lstm

Getting memory error while doing Text Generation using LSTM when i am converting the target variable to categorical using kera[Below is the image for the memory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKV27.png)s

Comment: If you could add little more info and code, I could help. Thanks

Comment: I got the answer I am using 4gb RAM instead I have to use 8gb that will process my data.